# Number of rows in Oracle SQL Select?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I need to know how many records were returned in a select in oracle.  Currently, I do two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(ITEM_ID) FROM MY_ITEMS;

SELECT * FROM MY_ITEMS;
```

I need to know the COUNT but I hate doing two queries.  Is there a way to do:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_ITEMS
```

and then find out how many records are in there?

Answer (score 38):

> Is there a way to do:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM MY_ITEMS
> ```
>
> and then find out how many records are in there?

If you want it to be in this exact order, you can fetch all records on the client and count their number (almost all client libraries provide a function for that).

You can also do:

```
SELECT  i.*, COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM    my_items i
```

, which will return you the count along with each record.

Comment: If you want to do this at the database level, I agree with the second suggestion. You can see an example here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions032.htm#i82697

Comment: Performance wise I think this should be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: what if I need to put where clause inside over(), for example SELECT  i.*, COUNT(*) OVER (where prod = 6)
FROM    my_items i

Comment: @user1512999: please post it as a separate question.

Comment: Essa é uma das coisas mais lindas que eu já vi! Não sei porque a resposta não foi aceita!

Comment: Over 13 years later, I was able to adapt this with a PARTITION BY in the OVER() clause for my scenario.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working in PL/SQL, you can use the SQL%ROWCOUNT pseudo-variable to get the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement. Might save you some effort.

Comment: how to evaluate/get this variable value?

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: @PeitiLi You have to use this pseudo-variable into PL scope. Like this `dbms_output.put_line('Last select fetched ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows');`

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do the trick.

```
WITH 
base AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MY_ITEMS
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base) kount,
       base.*
FROM base
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just unsure about the table aliases, I don't remember in Oracle if they require 'AS' or not. But this should work.

```
select mt.*, c.Cntr
    from MyTable mt
        , (select COUNT(*) as Cntr
               from MyTable
           ) c
```

Comment: The OP specifically requested a method that would not require two queries; munging the two queries into one, that still does exactly the same amount of extra unnecessary work, is not a great answer, IMHO.