# Max and Selection of multiple columns in the same Query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Could anybody tell me that how can I achieve this Query in oracle

```
select column1, columns2, max(rownumber) from table where .....;
```

Explanation: Select Query is so complicated and I need max to give UI Side "total count" of the record for paging and i will send the data only 20 or 30 records based on the paging size not full record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of rows in Oracle SQL Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884183/number-of-rows-in-oracle-sql-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select column1, columns2, 
       count(*) over () as total_count
from table 
where .....;
```